# Pandas ValueError: "Columns must be same length as key"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Labs for this.
I'm trying to split a column into two and receiving the error "Columns must be same length as key"

[dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpaqj.png)

Code for the first split:

```
two_new_columns = ['Rank', 'Title']
df[two_new_columns] = df['Rank & Title'].str.split('.', 1, expand=True)

df
```

[full error thrown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ6WQ.png)

Using str.extract, I get the correct column headers, but no rows to follow.
[str.extract image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX7di.png)

Any suggestions as to how to fix this error?
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymB7Y.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `.` is regex special character, so add `regex=False` for not processing it like regex patatern:

```
df[two_new_columns] = df['Rank & Title'].str.split('.', 1, expand=True, regex=False)
```

Or escape regex by `\`:

```
df[two_new_columns] = df['Rank & Title'].str.split(r'\.', 1, expand=True)
```

Alternative solution:

```
df1 = df['Rank & Title'].str.extract(r'(?P<Rank>\d+)\.(?P<Title>.*)')
```

Comment: Using the first solution I get the error output, "split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex'." Using the second, I get the same error thrown as before.

Comment: @SimplyAbstruse - tested and first working for pandas `1.4.0`+, second tested for lower versions and working well for me. Added another solution with `str.extract`, can you test?

Comment: Using the extract method, I get the correct columns, but no rows. I have added an image in the original post.

Comment: @SimplyAbstruse - what is `print (df['Rank & Title'].head().tolist())` ?

Comment: That outputs: [ ]

Comment: @SimplyAbstruse - so it means there are no data? In original DataFrame for column `'Rank & Title'` not exist any row? Or you test after `df = df['Rank & Title'].str.extract(r'(?P<Rank>\d+)\.(?P<Title>.*)')` not before `df = df['Rank & Title'].str.extract(r'(?P<Rank>\d+)\.(?P<Title>.*)')` ?

Comment: I tested it right after my original dataframe, so before str.extract

Comment: @SimplyAbstruse - so there are no data? DataFrame is empty? `print (df)` return empty DataFrame?

Comment: Oh yes, it does return "Empty Dataframe" How?

Comment: @SimplyAbstruse - no idea, something wrong. Because my solution working well.

Comment: I cleared my outputs and reran the code. Now print(df) and head().tolist() are working before str.extract, but return [ ] after

Comment: @SimplyAbstruse - If there are data `df[two_new_columns] = df['Rank & Title'].str.split(r'\.', 1, expand=True)` should working well. What is exactly `print (df['Rank & Title'].head().tolist())` ? I need it for test.

Comment: ahh nevermind str.extract worked! thank you

Comment: would you know how I would go about splitting the years from the titles? I am new to splitting and very confused.

Comment: @SimplyAbstruse - I cannot read data from picture, so ask for `print (df['Rank & Title'].head().tolist())`. Can you add output to comment?

Comment: `['1. The Shawshank Redemption (1994)', '2. The Godfather (1972)',  '3. The Dark Knight (2008)', '4. The Godfather: Part II (1974)', '5. 12 Angry Men (1957)']`